# Can't create k3d cluster

Tags: kubernetes, k3d

This must be a newbie question. Going through a k3d [tutorial](https://www.suse.com/c/introduction-k3d-run-k3s-docker-src/). Trying to do

```
$ k3d cluster create mycluster --api-port 127.0.0.1:6445 --servers 3 --agents 2 --volume '/home/me/mycode:/code@agent[*]' --port '8080:80@loadbalancer'

FATA[0000] failed to filter nodes for volume mapping '/root/k3d:/code': Failed to parse node filters: invalid format or empty subset in 'agent[*]'
```

What's going on?

Edit: this worked:

```
k3d cluster create mycluster33  --api-port 127.0.0.1:6445 --servers 3 --agents 2 --volume '/root/k3d/mycode:/code@agent:0' --port '8080:80@loadbalancer'
```

Difference between k3d versions?